# How to define a type in TypeScript based on another type, making some properties optional and removing others?

Tags: typescript

Let's say that I have a DTO (Data Transfer Object) representing a model. This DTO includes the model ID, a creation date and a last updated date.

I want to define another type based on this one, where I simply want to have all properties of the model DTO as they are defined, but make the ID optional, such that the new DTO can serve as a common DTO for creating new instances as well as updating existing ones (a `CreateUpdateSomeModelDTO` type)?

Optionally, I would like to remove the creation date and last updated date from this new type, in cases where these should be set by the server, or database, and not by the client.

How would I define this new type in TypeScript, based on this initial DTO type:

```js
type Product = {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    shortDescription: string | null;
    imageUrl: string | null;
    createdAt: Date;
    updatedAt: Date;
    productCategoryId: string;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use the standard library type utilities `Omit`, `Partial` and `Pick` to do this.

In TypeScript 4.7, these utility types are defined as:

```js
/** Construct a type with the properties of T except for those in type K. */
type Omit<T, K extends string | number | symbol> = { [P in Exclude<keyof T, K>]: T[P]; }

/** Make all properties in T optional */
type Partial<T> = { [P in keyof T]?: T[P] | undefined; }

/** From T, pick a set of properties whose keys are in the union K */
type Pick<T, K extends keyof T> = { [P in K]: T[P]; }
```

Given the model type:

```js
type Product = {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    shortDescription: string | null;
    imageUrl: string | null;
    createdAt: Date;
    updatedAt: Date;
    productCategoryId: string;
}
```

the solution would be:

```js
type CreateUpdateProductInput = Omit<
  Product,
  "id" | "createdAt" | "updatedAt"
> &
  Partial<Pick<Product, "id">>;
```

`Omit` removes the properties defined in the union from the input type and keeps the rest, `Pick` picks just the `id` property, and `Partial` makes that property optional. `&` is used to intersect the resulting types, creating a new type that has all properties from all the intersected types.

This was not in the question, but it's worth mentioning that you can also add additional properties to this definition by intersecting with another type definition, like this:

```js
type CreateUpdateProductInput = Omit<
  Product,
  "id" | "createdAt" | "updatedAt"
> &
  Partial<Pick<Product, "id">> & { extraCustomField: string };
```

Comment: Probably worth creating generic utility types for this.